# Enum returning string value in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, enums

I have come across a piece of code in my Web API project, which has a class of this structure:

```
public class QuestionDto
{
    public bool disabled {get;set;}
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int order {get;set;}
    public PositionDto pagePosition {get;set;}
    public string title {get;set;}
}

public enum PositionDto
{
    FullWidth = 0,
    Half = 1
}
```

There is an API call that returns `QuestionDto`, along the lines of:

```
[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(QuestionDto))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCategoryQuestions()
{
    return Ok(new QuestionDto { PagePosition = PagePositionDto.Half });
}
```

Here is a snip from the Chrome console network tab showing the repsonse for this API call:

[image]

How can the enum be returning its text value, rather than its int value?

To confuse this even further, if I then take this same class structure and copy and paste to a differrent project, the api call returning this object will return the int value - which is what I would expect.

So how can the first project be returning the string value?

Is there some setting somewhere which can make this enum return its string value?

Comment: how do you serialize the enum?

Comment: I would guess (and without **a lot more info** it would be a guess) that you have defined a custom serilizer somewhere in your code (probably in the `Startup.cs` but this can vary)

Comment: @Liam that is the correct answer - if you add that as an answer I will mark it as correct

Comment: Try searching project for something like this - StringEnumConverter. If it's added to global api configuration then it's the reason why its returning string.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is a setting that can be added to a variable, that will return the string value in JSON.

It can either be set on the variable declaration like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public PositionDto pagePosition { get; set; }
```

or it can be set globally, like this:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```

Comment: how can do it global, where this code place ?, please replay

Comment: What is the `config` variable, where does it come from? In the original question, there's no such variable and no obvious way to retrieve it.

Comment: @lwchris I can’t see any reference to a config variable in this answer?

Comment: @Alex First line of second code block, `var json = config. ...`

Comment: @LWChris Typically you will need to this line of code in .NET 4.x in your 'WebApiConfig.cs' file within the App_Start folder. This contains a Register method passing in a HttpConfiguration object (config), where you setup stuff like http filters, route configuration, formatters etcetera

Comment: In `System.Text.Json.Serialization` you can use `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`

Answer (score 20):

If you are using asp.net core or dotnet 6, use JsonStringEnumConverter instead of StringEnumConverter
  `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]`

Answer (score 15):

For WebAPI with .Net 5.0 you can do this in `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs` for global solution to enums:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

Answer (score 8):

For .NET Core 6, use the following code in the Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
   options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

   options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition =
       JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
});
```

Comment: This is actually a good way of doing it throughout the whole project, not just endpoint specific. And is a modern approach

Answer (score 2):

Alex has the right answer - just to add a little - if you're using Newtonsoft.Json you'll need to include "using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;" to  have StringEnumConverter available.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
return Ok(new QuestionDto { PagePosition.Value = PagePositionDto.Half.Value });
```

Comment: Please elaborate how your code solves the issue.