# How to convert enum to string for a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have a object that is stored in dynamoDB, one of the property is list of enum and when it is stored, an integer values is stored instead of string.

I tried decorating with `JsonStringEnumConverter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum Category
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Air")]
    Air = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Car")]
    Car = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Hotel")]
    Hotel = 3,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Cruise")]
    Cruise = 4
}
```

Also I tried in the startup option.

```
.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Values is in below format:

```
"ContentAttributes": null,
"IsOrderFees": false,
"Categories": [
    4,
    1,
    2,
    3
]
```

I need in below format:

```
"ContentAttributes": null,
"IsOrderFees": false,
"Categories": [
    "Cruise",
    "Air",
    "Car",
    "Hotel"
]
```

Comment: Why would you want to store the string? Store the int..

Comment: What is problem with storing int?

Comment: The second JSON is invalid, because the enum strings are not inside double-quotes.

Comment: Unsure how the implementation looks, but this is a base feature of enums: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#conversions

Comment: @TMcKeown we cannot store in int because our client is not having any idea on the numbers they understand string.

Comment: @UweKeim It was just a dummy example, still I have edited, please check

Comment: Are the integer values used at all? They are not required when defining an enum. What does the parent object look like?

Comment: customer sending string is right.. storing in DB should be int. always.

Answer (score 0):

(updated)
in NET 7:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

minimal API:

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

or try to use Newtonsoft.

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
        });
```

in addition look at this url
[Enum returning string value in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48949595/enum-returning-string-value-in-webapi)

Comment: With no explanation on why to make such a big move as switching to another library, this seems like an overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the package `Macross.Json.Extensions` you don't need any attributes in the enum if you put `[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]` above the property in your object like this:

```
public enum Category
{
    Air = 1,
    Car = 2,
    Hotel = 3,
    Cruise = 4
}

public class YourObject
{
  [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]
  public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Macross.Json.Extensions" Version="3.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```